# How to source a key value paired file in bash escaping whitespace?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ cat foo.txt
a=1one
b=2two
c=3 three
d=4four

$ source foo.txt
bash: three: command not found...
```

Need to set all the variable listed in `foo.txt`, how to source this file by escaping the space character? foo.txt comes from other application, which I cannot control, or is there an alternative to `source` ?

Comment: @anubhava, ...if you trust it. If you don't, much better to explicitly parse.

Comment: @anubhava, is there a command line option with sed you proposed? or should I create a sed'ed file and source that new file?

Comment: @rodee, `sed -i` modifies a file in-place (well, in theory; actually, it creates a new temporary file and renames it over the original). If you have a baseline POSIX `sed` that doesn't support it, then yes, you can leave that option out, redirect output to a file, and source that file (or, if you have a new enough bash that this isn't buggy, `source <(sed ...)` -- though that has the same security problems that `source` has altogether, so I don't recommend it).

Comment: @anubhava, what's the significance of whitespace before '*' in your first comment, `s/ *$/"/`, sourcing fails if I remove this whitespace, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `*` in regex is a modifier meaning "zero-or-more of the prior thing", in this case, meaning zero or more spaces. If there is no prior thing, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks Charles, yes, that was my understanding too, but there is no space at the end of line(before `$`) in `foo.txt`, so how is it working?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Zero spaces can be matched by a pattern that looks for "zero-or-more spaces", after all, because zero is in the set of zero-or-more.

Comment: oops yes, stupid me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

If the output is so regular, you could try to preprocess the file using `sed` like this:

```
$ sed -e "s/=/='/;s/$/'/" < foo.txt >sourced.env
```

and then source `sourced.env`. This will add a `'` just after the `=` and add an ending `'`.

Comment: If we don't trust the program writing the file, this is a very bad idea; if it contains `foo=$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, then the literal quotes inside the file will cancel out the ones added by `sed`.

Comment: I can trust that file.

Comment: Mmm. Be sure. At one of my former employers they trusted filenames to be safely generated, until a buffer overflow in a 3rd-party C library used by the Python script that was generating content dumped random content from memory into the names, which happened to contain a whitespace-surrounded asterisk; an unsafely-written script tried to delete the file, and Bad Things happened. Which is to say -- weird things happen, sometimes; it's better to write safe code even when you don't think you need to, and then you're doing things the right way when it *does* matter, expectedly or otherwise.